# one button and two differents views

Tags: java, model-view-controller, view

I'm building my application applying MVC pattern.Following this guide [mvc guide](http://www.austintek.com/mvc/), I would make an application made of a button.when I press button appear me another view when I repress the button appear me the previously view.how can I made ?some advices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well **Button will act as the Controller** here........

If you want **always to show the same View again and again, by repressing the Button, use Singleton Principle**

If not, **you can initialize a new View again, from within the onClick() method of ActionListener...**

**Edited:**

```
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                //Execute when button is pressed

                     new Frame();           // Creates a new frame
            }
        });
```

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using the singleton pattern in this case.

Comment: If same view is to be returned again and again, i think Singleton will do.......Thats what he wanted right...

Comment: Why would he need a singleton for that? Isn't it just enough to create *one instance* of the view he wants to show / hide?

Comment: I have two totally different views...pressing button appear VIEW 1 repressing button appear VIEW 2.

Comment: @Mazzy thats very easy, read my answer carefully...at the end i have written the answer to your question